# Expressing a random variable as a sum of indicator functions

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus

Suppose a stochastic process $X = \{X_t, \, 0 \leq t \leq n \}$.

I have seen some of my friends writing the random variable $X_t$ as:

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~X_t = X_t \, \sum_{i \, = 0}^{n} \mathbb{1}_{\{t \, = \, i\}} = \sum_{i \, = \, 0}^{n} X_i \, \mathbb{1}_{\{t \, = \, i\}}\,$,

where $\mathbb{1}_{\{t \, = \, i\}}$ is the indicator function that gives $1$ if the event $\{t \, = \, i\}$ is true, and $0$ otherwise.

Is the above expression correct? If correct, why? can someone explain to me in detail what is happening? why for example the sum is used and not another operation?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since neither $\ i\ $ nor $\ t\ $ is a random variable, $\ \{t=i\}\ $ is not an event in your probability space, and $\ \mathbb{1}_{\{t=i\}}\ $ isn't a random variable. The only sensible meaning I can think of for $\ \{t=i\}\ $ is a singleton set containing the truth-value "true" if $\ t=i\ $, or the truth-value "false" if $\ t\ne i\ $, and $\ \mathbb{1}_{\{t=i\}}\ $ would then simply be [Kronecker's delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta). In that case, the equations
$$
X_t=X_t\sum_{i=0}^n \mathbb{1}_{\{t=i\}}=\sum_{i=0}^n X_i\mathbb{1}_{\{t=i\}}
$$
are true because $\ \mathbb{1}_{\{t=i\}}=1\ $ if and only if $\ i=t\ $ and is $0$ otherwise, so the only term that contributes to either sum is the $\ t^\text{th}\ $.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Are you sure that the indicator function here is not a random variable? it sounds a bit strange to not consider it as a random variable right?

Comment: I suppose you could treat it as a "random variable" which is constant, but I think that's apt to be confusing.  The variables $\ t\ $ and $\ i\ $ here are indices which can take on any of the values $\ 0,1,2,\dots,n\ $, but their values don't depend on which outcome of the your probability space occurs, so neither does the value of $\ \mathbb{1}_{\{t=i\}}\ $.

Comment: In fact I also think that because in the class we always treated this indicator function as a constant. BTW I will check about it!

Comment: In fact $\sum_{i \, = 0}^{n} \mathbb{1}_{\{t \, = \, i\}}$ is equal to $1$. I asked today my professor.